# Prevent Web Site Redirection?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser, redirection

I have a web site I visit. When I click a link, the link is something like:

```
a.com/something/blah.php
```

Then moments later the url in the browser changes to something like:

```
a.com/somethingelse/blahblah.php
```

Is there a way with any browser (especially firefox) to have it ask me before redirecting?
I have tried the 'ask me before redirecting' feature in firefox but in this case since it redirects to its own site it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way with Firefox (if you want the instructions for other browsers, just ask through a comment).

1. Open the Firefox browser
2. Click **Tools** then **Options** then **Advanced**
3. Select the **General** tab
4. Under **Accessibility**, select: Warn me when web sites try to redirect or reload the page
5. Click **OK**

Firefox will now warn (notify) you before it redirects you to a new webpage.

Alternatively, you can consider using an extension to prevent redirects.  [NoRedirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/) should do the job just fine.